# vector::insert segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a class like this:

```
classA
{
public:
  classA()
   {
     //Here I am doing something but nothing related to vector

   }

   void updateVec(int idx, int value)
   {
     //Here, I want to update vector vector based on args passed
     myVec.insert(myVec.begin() + idx, value);

   }

  std::vector<int> myVec;
}
```

Now, I am getting segmentation fault on insert statement. Do I need to initialize vector somewhere?

Comment: I presume, it's a vector of ints `std::vector<int>`...

Comment: yes, somehow, it got removed in formatting.

Comment: Which parameter to `updateVec` make your application crash ? What is in your `vector` at this time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it seems that you did not initialize it properly.

**initialization for use as local var**
Create a vector of ints, size 3, initialized to 0

`std::vector<int> myvector (3,0);`

**Short example of how to initialize(and then resize) a vector in a class's constructor**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
   A(int size);
   ~A();
   void updateVec(int idx, int value);
   void print();
private:
  std::vector<int> myVec;
};

A::A(int size) {
    myVec.resize(size);
}

A::~A() {
}

void A::updateVec(int idx, int value) {
     myVec.insert(myVec.begin() + idx, value);
}

void A::print() {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it=myVec.begin(); it!=myVec.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << " " << *it;
    }
}

int main() {
    A* a = new A(10);
    a->updateVec(2,10);
    a->print();
}
```

Here is documentation/example on how to use a vector in C++
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/

Comment: You cannot initialize a member vector this way.

Comment: No, I did not initialize it at all, just declared it. As I am not sure how many elements I need to put in it.

Comment: @user333422 You need to initialize it to some value, because otherwise you are trying to insert into an index that does not exist (or isn't allocated), which is why you are getting a `segfault`

Comment: @Kenny Cason: As a local variable, it's correct. But that syntax cannot be used to initialize a class member vector, you need to .resize or to use the class constructors initializer list.

Comment: @Erik ah Ok, i see what you are saying. yes he needs to initialize it in his constructor. I was just trying to illustrate that he needs to initialize it, but I will update my answer. Thanks

Comment: had a typo in the constructor. make note of `myVec.resize(size)`

Answer (score 4):

Segmentation fault means you're trying to access/write into memory that has not (yet) been allocated. In your case, depending on value of `idx`, `myVec.begin() + idx` can refer to memory that is out of vector's allocated zone. Before inserting, you need to make sure your vector can hold at least `idx` elements. `updateVec` should check the current size of the vector, and if it is not big enough, it should call `vector::reserve` to allocate enough room so new element can be inserted.

Comment: Not quite, `idx` must be `<= vec.size()`. Capacity, allocated zone and reserve have nothing to do with it: inserting anything beyond the end of the vector still won't do any good, even if the memory has been reserved. - As to error handling, it is up to the asker to decide what they need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. Vectors start off empty. Any attempt to access an item past the end of the vector will result in an error.

To suggest a solution we'll need to know if the vector needs to change size dynamically - or if it is a fixed size, at what point in time will you know what size it needs to be.

Also, if you update the 17th elemnt of the vector, but at the time it only contains 10 items, do you want items 11 to 16 to be created as well?

Comment: Its size changes dynamically. Just before I do insert, I come to know, at what position, I need to insert. There may be some empty positions, like in your e.g. 11 to 16 might not contain anything meaningful.

Comment: Accessing a vector past the end is undefined behavior. The phrase "will result in an error" may push the view that you will get a crash (that is - unfortunately - NOT true). In C++ there are no runtime error angels, only undefined behavior daemons.

Comment: @user333422 - have you used the STL `map` before? It may be a better option than vector if you expect to have empty positions. How many items do you think may be added over the run of the app? How often do you retrieve items? And, if you try to retrieve an "empty position" what behaviour would you like?

Comment: Hi, I also realized that map will be a better solution for this, so I am changing my code right now to use a map.