# C++ vector giving segmentation fault when inserting/emplacing elements in arbitrary positions

Tags: c++, vector

The following gives a *segmentation fault* when I try to insert in position 3.

```
vector<int> a;
a.insert(a.begin(), 10);
a.insert(a.begin()+1, 9);
a.insert(a.begin()+3, 7);
```

I tought it was because I was exceeding the *capacity*, in fact this code works:

```
vector<int> a=vector<int>(3);
a.insert(a.begin(), 10);
a.insert(a.begin()+1, 9);
a.insert(a.begin()+3, 7);
```

...but if you try this, it causes *segmentation fault* like the first, although the *capacity* is updating correctly

```
vector<int> a=vector<int>(3);
a.insert(a.begin(), 10);
a.insert(a.begin()+1, 9);
a.insert(a.begin()+3, 7);
cout<< a.capacity() << endl;
a.reserve(100);
cout<< a.capacity() << endl;
a.insert(a.begin()+16, 4);
```

It seems to be a weird behaviour of the C++ vector implementation, doesn't it?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible dupplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028156/vectorinsert-segmentation-fault

Comment: rather than assuming, why not read the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` has separate notions of *capacity* and *size*. The size is the number of elements currently stored in the vector, whereas the capacity is the number of elements which can be stored in the amount of space currently allocated.

`std::reserve` may change the capacity; i.e. it can cause more memory to be allocated.

`std::resize` may change the size; i.e. it can cause elements to be added or removed from the vector.

In your third snippet, the vector is initialized with a size of `3`. You then go on to `reserve` space for `100` elements, but no extra elements are added, so `a.begin()+16` points past `a.end`. If you change `reserve` to `resize` then your behaviour will be as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access memory that isn't yet created. `Insert` adds  space for an element to the vector, and in the first two inserts you're referencing memory that has been allocated ok (the first and second elements of the vector). The third `insert` is attempting to reference the forth element of the array but that hasn't been allocated/created.

Comment: Look at the third code snippet: how do you explain that?

Comment: The vector is still only of size 6 and you're attempting to access the 17th element. Instead of printing 'a.capacity()' look at 'a.size()'

Comment: @vvigilante actually, no further explanation is necessary – it's UB, so anything can be expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

> I tought it was because I was exceeding the *capacity*

You thought wrong. Inserting beyond `vector::end()` has undefined behaviour. The end iterator always points after the last element. The *capacity* is irrelevant.